# How to change default swagger.json file path?

Tags: nginx, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, consul

I have created Ngnix-Consul Docker setup referred https://github.com/nginxinc/NGINX-Demos/tree/master/consul-template-demo.

And have created many microservices. So All the microservices are accessible only after adding the service name for e.g.

```
http://example.com/service_name/get_data
```

All is working fine then I wanted to add swagger for all microservices so tried with below snippet
I am able to access swagger ui by using

```
http://example.com/service_name/ui
```

But the problem is I am not able to load swagger.json in that ui as its trying to access swagger.json on below url

```
http://example.com/swagger.json
```

but the json file is on

```
http://example.com/service_name/swagger.json
```

How can I change the default path of swagger.json?

The applications in microservices are created in python-flask
    I have tried below snippet

```
swagger: "2.0"
    info:
      description: "Add service"
      version: "1.0.0"
      title: "Add Service"
      contact:
        email: "abc@efg.com"
      license:
        name: "s1.0"
        url: "http://sample.com"
    host: "abc.efg.com"
    tags:
    - name: "add service"
      description: "service"
    - name: "delete service"
      description: "data"
    schemes:
    - "http"
    paths:
      /service_name/get_data:
```

and even I have tried to add basePath in the swagger.yaml file
then It did not even open swaggerui

```
swagger: "2.0"
    info:
      description: "Add service"
      version: "1.0.0"
      title: "Add Service"
      contact:
        email: "abc@efg.com"
      license:
        name: "s1.0"
        url: "http://sample.com"
    host: "abc.efg.com"
    basePath: "service_name"
    tags:
    - name: "add service"
      description: "service"
    - name: "delete service"
      description: "data"
    schemes:
    - "http"
    paths:
      /get_data:
```

Update:

```
from flask import Flask
import connexion

app = Flask(__name__)
app = connexion.App(__name__)
app.add_api('swagger.yaml')

//apis

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8090, debug=True)
```

Comment: Which python package are you using for swagger ui? How are you setting it up?

Comment: Please check my updated question. connexion is the package

Comment: Try `app.add_api('swagger.yaml', base_path='service_name')`

Comment: I had tried with basePath in swagger.yml.With this rest services are working but not swagger.json and ui

Comment: not in yaml but in the add_api call

Comment: No, its not working .{
  "detail": "The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.",
  "status": 404,
  "title": "Not Found",
  "type": "about:blank"
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171983/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-happy).

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem myself. The solution for me was to disable path rewrite in the NGINX level, so that the microservice would receive the full url:

Before:

```
Request: 
http://example.com/service_name/get_data

Service sees:
/get_data
```

After:

```
Request: 
http://example.com/service_name/get_data

Service sees:
/service_name/get_data
```

Only then you can specify basePath as "*service_name*" in the swagger.yaml file:

```
swagger: "2.0"
    info:
      description: "Add service"
      version: "1.0.0"
      title: "Add Service"
    host: "abc.efg.com"
    basePath: "service_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

If file swagger.json is static in NGINX config you can make alias rule like this:

```
location ^~ /swagger.json {
    alias /path_to/swagger.json;
}
```

Comment: No I cannot do that as I have multiple microservices , each having its own swagger.json

Comment: possible problem is here
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-servlet/src/main/java/io/swagger/servlet/listing/ApiDeclarationServlet.java
in doGet method:
        if ("/swagger.json".equals(pathInfo)) {
            response.getWriter().println(Json.mapper().writeValueAsString(swagger));
        } else if ("/swagger.yaml".equals(pathInfo)) {
            response.getWriter().println(Yaml.mapper().writeValueAsString(swagger));
        } else {
            response.setStatus(404);
        }

Comment: I think to solve this problem you can place each service on its own subdomain like this http://service_name.example.com/